# Rank order in Excel

Tags: excel, function, rank

I am using the RANK function in Excel to return a rank value of my data.  Using this function is fine but what I need to be able to do is return a value for Top 2 equal rankings in the form of `=1`, or `1=`. Following on from that I will need the third entry to show rank 2 rather than 3.  This is a particular quirk of how I need to report this data and I cannot find anywhere how I might do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$12,A2)>1,(SUMPRODUCT((A2<A$2:A$12)/COUNTIF(A$2:A$12,A$2:A$12))+1)&"=",SUMPRODUCT((A2<A$2:A$12)/COUNTIF(A$2:A$12,A$2:A$12))+1)
```

Assuming your data starts in A2 and extends to A12.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the `RANK` function is to essentially "skip" numbers if two numbers in a set share the same value. Assuming that the data is in `A1:A5`, the following (non-array) function will rank a set of numbers in ascending order without skipping numbers:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1>A$1:A$5)/COUNTIF(A$1:A$5,A$1:A$5))+1
```

You can also change the formula to descending order by simply changing the comparison in the numerator of the `SUMPRODUCT` formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1<A$1:A$5)/COUNTIF(A$1:A$5,A$1:A$5))+1
```